# OctoberCMS - Mail::send(), Undefined variables - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, octobercms

I am trying to send the ***SAME*** email to *multiple* addresses given from an array `$emails`.

I created a class called `SendMail`, and inside is a `sendPost()` method that accepts 2 arguments:
`($post, $emails)`

Here is my code:

```
class SendMail {

public static function sendPost($post, $emails)
{
        Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.message', $post, function($message) {

            $message->to($emails);
            $message->from('mail@compuflexcorp.com', 'Compuflex Mail');
            $message->subject($post['subject']);
            $message->replyTo($post['email']);

        });
    }
}
```

The problem is, I keep receiving an error:

> "Undefined variable $emails" on Line 14 of C:\...\SendMail.php

*Line 14:* `$message->to($emails);`

What I have tried:

1. I checked to see if I can access the `$post` and `$emails` variables *inside* of `sendPost()`, but outside of `Mail::send()`. And the answer is ***YES***, I can access the information inside of `$post` and `$emails` inside of `sendPost()`, so the variables are, in fact, being passed to the `sendPost()` method.
2. I, at first, thought it had something to do with the fact that `$emails` is not one of the arguments for `Mail::send()`, so I put `$post` and `$emails` into one array called `$vars`, but then I got the error:

> "Undefined variable $vars" on Line 14 of C:\...\SendMail.php

So, I realized that the issue seems to be that I can't pass any variables to `Mail::send()`, or in other words, I just don't know how to...

Any help would be greatly appreciated...
Thomas Yamakaitis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the $emails variable as follows:

```
class SendMail {

public static function sendPost($post, $emails)
{
        Mail::send('acme.blog::mail.message', $post, function($message) use ($emails) {

            $message->to($emails);
            $message->from('mail@compuflexcorp.com', 'Compuflex Mail');
            $message->subject($post['subject']);
            $message->replyTo($post['email']);

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if it works then mark it as correct answer please so will be helpful to other people as well.

Comment: I will, there's like a 3 minute waiting period.

Comment: @HasanTareque can you tell me what is the use of $post here and how to pass this $post to sendPost method, as I am calling this as Form Submit Method.

Also if you can help me how to pass the Data to the Maul View/template.